# PostThreadMessage Fails to "Cleanly" Close Application

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I have been developing an application (VB.Net) which allows a user to open PDF files through Adobe Acrobat.  These files are subject to change at any given moment so instead of opening directly from the server, I copy the file to the local drive and open that instead.  Using a File System Watcher, I am able to inform the user that a change has been made to the file.

What I would like to accomplish is to 'cleanly' close the file and reopen it for the user should they respond yes to a message dialog.

So far this is what I have done:

```
Dim threadId As Int32 = 0
Dim id As Int32 = 0

'hWnd is obtained from the Win32 Function: GetForegroundWindow()
'when called by a WinEventHook when the Active Window changes.

threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, id)    'Id always returns 0, Not sure why
PostThreadMessageW(threadId, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)    'WM_CLOSE Does not seem to close the
                                                ', however WM_QUIT always closes the window

If WaitForSingleObject(hWnd, 1000) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 Then  'The returned result always seems to be -1
    TerminateProcess(hWnd, 0) 'This does not do what it's supposed to do.
End If
```

Even though I am able to get the Window to quit (only using WM_QUIT), when I try to reopen the file using:

```
Process.Start(FilePath)
```

the Acrobat states - "There was an error opening this document.  This file is already open or in use by another application."

I find this message to be weird because before I reach Process.Start(), I delete the file if it exists and recreate it.  No exceptions are thrown in Visual Studio, so I am at a loss as to why this is not working.

I have obtained reference from this link - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/178893

I should also note, that I had attempted a similar approach by tracking the ProcessId of each window opened by the application.  Using the Id I created a new process object to which I used: Process.Close(), Process.CloseMainWindow(), and Process.Kill().  I was alerted with the same message as mentioned previously.

I have no clue why these options are not working, but it's obvious I did something wrong.  Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, or alternate methods to accomplish my end goal.  Thanks!

Comment: This is just buggy code.  FileSystemWatcher only tells you that there was a change to the file, it does not tell you that an app closed the file.  It is in fact *very* likely that the file is still open, you cannot predict when the app closes it.  You'll have to periodically try to open it yourself with FileShare.None, if that doesn't fail then you know nobody else has the file opened.  PostThreadMessage() is a bug as well, you must use PostMessage().

Comment: `GetForegroundWindow` is a bug. `PostThreadMessageW` is a bug. `TerminateProcess` is a bug. You don't appear to have the background necessary to safely implement what you are after.

Comment: @HansPassant The file is closed and I'm not using the File System Watcher to detect closed files.  I know it doesn't do that nor do I make mention of using it in this way.  You mention the code is buggy, but without explanation.  Could you elaborate?  I would like to learn what it is I'm doing wrong which is why I posted the question in the first place.  Anything at all would be nice; maybe documentation regarding how to open and close files "properly"?

Comment: @IInspectable No offense, but your comment isn't necessary or useful.  Everyone lacks background, which is the point of learning, which is the whole point of this site.  Or did I miss the section saying this site was for experts only?

Comment: You can always flag a comment as inappropriate, once you have gained [enough reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to do so.

Comment: You're trying to learn how to do things in a very dangerous and counterproductive way. This code is full of comments that express confusion as to what's going on because of fundamental misunderstandings about how Windows works. I'll see if I can explain IInspectable's "useless" comment in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is fundamentally flawed, and while I understand that you're trying to learn how to do things, this is a rather advanced thing to do, and the comments in your code indicate that you don't understand enough of how Windows works to do these things.

I'll start by picking apart your comments:

> hWnd is obtained from the Win32 Function: GetForegroundWindow()
>   when called by a WinEventHook when the Active Window changes.

This is a clumsy way to detect Adobe Reader. There are better options, such as `FindWindow()`, that don't require user interaction or hooking.

Furthermore, what happens if I change the active window to something other than Adobe Reader? Now you're interacting with a foreign window that isn't Adobe Reader at all! Your code will close/quit/etc. a random program and you'll never realize it. This is part of why `GetForegroundWindow()` is a bug, and [there are far worse things that you can do with the foreground window handle](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/27/4072156.aspx).

> Id always returns 0, Not sure why

I'm not sure why either, but...

> PostThreadMessageW

This is bad because [if the program is in a modal loop, your thread message disappears](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/27/412565.aspx). But you have a window handle; the [`SendMessage()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that it will handle cross-process and cross-thread window messages for you.

> WM_CLOSE

In addition, messages posted with `PostThreadMessage()` are not given to a specific window (you process them in your *message pump* directly). `WM_CLOSE` is a message that windows handle; you need to send it to a window, not to a thread.

> WM_CLOSE Does not seem to close the [window], however WM_QUIT always closes the window

`WM_QUIT` tells the message pump that it should stop processing messages. You're not telling the window to close, you're telling the program to terminate!

> WaitForSingleObject(hWnd

`WaitForSingleObject()` waits for kernel objects, such as mutexes and event objects. Window handles are not kernel objects (they are window manager objects), so you can't use `WaitForSingleObject()` to wait for a window to close. Use WinEvents for that.

> TerminateProcess(hWnd, 0)

Again, window handles are separate from process handles, so you can't terminate a process by giving it a window handle.

And by terminating Adobe Reader like this, you wind up doing other nefarious things, like closing whatever other PDFs I happen to have open at the time, or not letting annotation plugins clean up after themselves.

---

I'm not sure what I would suggest you start with, since I don't know how familiar you are with the Windows API. But I would recommend trying to write a moderately-sized pure-Windows-API application before trying something like this, because the misunderstandings shown here are in places that are fundamental to Windows programming.

But let's approach your original problem: You want to create a PDF file that is changed often, and want Reader to update itself when the PDF changes. But the way you think you're doing this has issues. What if the person was looking at a specific page? Unless their Reader was set up to save positions in PDF files, they'll be thrown back to page 1 when the PDF is reopened. Annotations that the reader may have made will also be lost.

You should investigate whether Reader provides a feature, if not an API, for live updates. Mabye even consider trying to write a plugin for Reader to do this, if one is not already available.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this in-depth answer.  It was what I was looking for and gives me an idea where to start.  Though I'd like to clear things up.  It might help you help me.

Comment: I do use a WinEventHook to get the Active Window, which is why I'm using GetForegroundWindow(). The PDFs that are being viewed have a naming standard which is easy to thin out using Regex.  Additionally they are 1pg docs and they won't be modified by the user.  I need to know if the server copy changes, which I have been able to detect the changes.  The app at the point asks the user if they would like to "restart" the file.  (Restart is getting the server copy and creating a new local copy of the updated PDF).

Comment: I have been having a hard time determining which functions I should use to close Adobe Acrobat and then reopen the local copy of the PDF.  Luckily, I do not need to worry about page position or annotations (none will be made by the user).  I just simply need to "cleanly" close the file.  I'd like to know which function/s would be best suited for this task, so that when I go to reopen the file, I do not get an alert stating the file is still open.

On a side note, thanks for explaining a little more about the Window handles and process handles.

Comment: I will accept this as the correct answer by the way.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to implement what you are after is to use the official [Acrobat Interapplication Communication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FIAC_DevApp_Architecture%2FIAC_DevApp_Architecture.htm). It supports all operations you wish to use through [DDE Messages](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FIAC_API_DDE_Messages%2FIAC_API_DDE_Messages.htm), or [OLE Automation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FIAC_API_OLE_Objects%2FIAC_API_OLE_Objects.htm%23TOC_OLE_Automation2bc-1&rhtocid=_7_1_0).

The [Acrobat SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/overview.html) is available through this [link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/sdk/eula.html).